# How can I remove an item from a spinner when it has been already selected on another spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have 3 spinners in my code with the same 4 choices. However I would like that when a choice is selected on a certain spinner, that same choice gets removed from the next one so that no spinners can have the same choices.

How can I remove an item from a spinner when it has been already selected on another spinner?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `List` of choices, when the user selects an `Item` it is added to the `List` and that `Item` is removed from the other `List` that backs all 3 spinners. Then you notify the changes to the list.

```
List<String> choices = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>():

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
          choices.add(options.get(position));
          options.remove(position);
          adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}

});
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
          choices.add(options.get(position));
          options.remove(position);
          adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}

});
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
          choices.add(options.get(position));
          options.remove(position);
          adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}

});
```

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you so much!